# How to use the adAdjacence function in ForceDirected?

Tags: javascript, json, graph, jit, infovis

I am working on a network graph (ForceDirected) in Java Infovis Toolkit: http://thejit.org/ "The jit". I need to draw the nodes in the first place and then add the adjacencies to each node created. I have to use addAdjacence function defined in the library, but I don't know how.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose fd is the graph object, we need to call the following function -

```
fd.graph.addAdjacence({id:123}, {id:167022});
```

where we pass two objects. Here 123 is the new node, 167022 is an existing node.